# Get .txt file instead of .jpg - using Webclient and DownloadFile();

Tags: c#, jpeg, webclient

Get .txt file instead of .jpg - using `Webclient` and `DownloadFile();`

I'm trying to download the .jpg from this URL:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_pK6J3MTn5co/S6kuH3aqbeI/AAAAAAAACUY/06axvmjU91k/s1600-h/avengers02_B&W_UL.jpg

Using this code:

```
private void TEST_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient MyDownloader = new WebClient();
    MyDownloader.DownloadFile(@"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_pK6J3MTn5co/S6kuH3aqbeI/AAAAAAAACUY/06axvmjU91k/s1600-h/avengers02_B&W_UL.jpg", @"c:\test.jpg");
}
```

However, when I run this, I end up with a file called **test.jpg**, which contains html mark up... :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>avengers02_B&amp;W_UL.jpg (image)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (top.location != self.location) top.location = self.location;
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_pK6J3MTn5co/S6kuH3aqbeI/AAAAAAAACUY/06axvmjU91k/s1600/avengers02_B%26W_UL.jpg" alt="[avengers02_B&amp;W_UL.jpg]" border=0>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I download the actual .jpg?

Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it. First you download the HTML content to a string and extract the correct image URL. Then use the correct URL to download the file.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 var path = @"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_pK6J3MTn5co/S6kuH3aqbeI/AAAAAAAACUY/06axvmjU91k/s1600-h/avengers02_B&W_UL.jpg";

 var content = client.DownloadString(path);
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=<img\s+[^>]*?src=(?<q>['""]))(?<url>.+?)(?=\k<q>)");
 var match = regex.Match(content);
 if (match.Success)
 {
     client.DownloadFile(match.Value, @"e:\test1.jpg");
 }
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use HtmlAgilityPack over regex to parse html, although this *specific* case is trivial enough for it not to matter.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome code -- this is definitely what I can use, and I get it.  Sorry for being dense, but hugely appreciate the patience and help!

Answer (score 2):

If server returns HTML to your request at particular Url you can't do much to force it to return something else at that Url.

What you can do is parse response with HtmlAgilityPack and find url to actual image and get it in another request.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but if you paste, or click on that URL it shows the correct image...  What am I not understanding?

Comment: @ChrisL - check view source in your browser or use Fiddler to see what server actually returns. You'll see HTML with IMG inside - nothing you can do about server's behavior (unless you know for sure that there is a way to set headers/query parameters for this particular type of requests on this particular server to return image directly).

Answer (score 0):

Clicking that link causes 2 downloads, first a page of HTML (mislabelled with suffix `.jpg`), and next an image in the HTML.

So perhaps you need to fetch the url of the `img` tag in the HTML fetched by the previous request?

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_pK6J3MTn5co/S6kuH3aqbeI/AAAAAAAACUY/06axvmjU91k/s1600/avengers02_B%26W_UL.jpg

I'm guessing that removing `-h` from the original URL might point to the actual file that you're after.

Here's hoping that you have permission to scrape these files...

Comment: This completely makes, thanks for making me see how to get this done!