# copyURLToFile is not downloading the file

Tags: java, image, fileutils

I am trying to download - http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_jNFMBZMTBvA/SjhABgh4-_I/AAAAAAAAA0U/Yvsaq_CreCs/s1600-h/hellboy+003.jpg using below code.But the downloaded file is not a valid image. Can someone helpme with this.I tried to encode this as well , but did not help

```
   var url = URL(originalUrl)
   FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, srcPath.toFile())
```

Comment: Please consider improving your question and posting some code that actually compiles. Otherwise the problem seems to depend on the url, the same code worked for me with the url of a different image and returned some html with javascript for the url you provided.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11303101/13149581) question deals with the same problem and even the same site, I'm not sure it's a duplicate since it's about c#, but the same approaches (extracting the url of the actual image from the html named as *.jpg) should help in the same way. The html url has `s1600-h`, while the image url just `s1600`, which seeems to be a recurring pattern. Depending on how general your code has to be, you could use a simplified approach or just change the url.